# Quantifier difference

Tags: quantifiers

What s the difference between $ n \in Z \implies n(n+1) =2k $ such that $k \in Z$ and $ \forall n \in Z \implies n(n+1) =2k $ such that $k \in Z$

Is this true:
$ (n \in Z \implies n(n+1) =2k $ such that $k \in Z) \implies \forall n \in Z; n(n+1) =2k $ such that$ k \in Z$

Comment: None, in that I cannot understand either: why have you introduced a $k$, only to use it  in the expression $2k/k$ which merely simplifies to $2$?

Comment: / means such that in my case

Comment: Impossible to understand ... The first one is an *equation* : $\dfrac {n}{n+1}=2k$.

Comment: The second one is a formula : $(\dfrac {n}{n+1}=2k) \to \forall n \ (\dfrac {n}{n+1}=2k)$ whose truth value depends on $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Rewritten in an unambiguous way

Comment: Perfect ! Rewritten the anwer according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this true that :
>
> > $(n ∈ \mathbb Z ⟹ \dfrac {n}{(n+1)} = 2k ) ⟹ ∀n ∈ \mathbb Z \dfrac {n}{(n+1)} = 2k \text { , for } k ∈ \mathbb Z$ ?

The formula :

> $\dfrac {n}{(n+1)} = 2k$

is about two unspecified numbers $n$ and $k$; it can be either true or false, according to the values we assign to them.

Specifically, the formula is true only for $n=k=0$.

This means that the *consequent* : $∀n ∈ \mathbb Z \dfrac {n}{(n+1)} = 2k$ is false.

Thus the original formula is false for $n=k=0$ (because in that case we have $\text T \to \text F$, which is $\text F$) and true in all other cases (because  $\text F \to \text F$ is $\text T$).

Comment: / doesn t mean division in my case, it means such that